# Display select menu values dynamically from database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery, How can I insert select menu values dynamically from salite db? I am able to select values how ca i insert into select menu? I need to insert in to "Choose subject" select box. Can it be done through onChange? Can any one help me.

Java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">  
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);  
  function onDeviceReady() {             
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"}); 
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql("select * from LOGS;", [], function(tx, res) {
        console.log("Row = " + i + ", subject= " + res.rows.item(i).subject ");
      });
    });  
  }  
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Choose subject</label>
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
        <option value="standard">Select subject</option>

    </select>
    <label for="select-choice-2" class="select">Choose test</label>
    <select name="select-choice-2" id="select-choice-2">
        <option value="standard">Select Test</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image] The User interface

Comment: are you able to retrieve data from server?

Comment: Yes, I am able to retrieve. I am printing it in console by the following statement,  console.log("Row = " + i + ", subject= " + res.rows.item(i).subject ");

Comment: post a sample of data retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare onDeviceReady before you use it :)

```
function onDeviceReady() {             

    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"}); 

    db.transaction(function(tx) {

        tx.executeSql("select * from LOGS;", [], function(tx, res) {

            console.log("Row = " + i + ", subject= " + res.rows.item(i).subject ");
        });
    });  
} 

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Apart from that I dont see why it shouldnt work. Bear in mind deviceready is a phonegap thing - you might consider using document onload if you want to use it in a different context.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. I'm not sure about thing in your mind.

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql("select * from LOGS;", [], function (tx, res) {
        $("#select-choice-1").append($("<option/> ", {
            value: res.rows.item(i).subject,
            html: res.rows.item(i).subject
        }));
    });
```

Comment: Will check , I need the same

Answer (score 0):

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"});
                                             db.transaction(function (tx) {
                                              tx.executeSql("select * from Locationlog;", [], function (tx, res) {
                                             for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                                               $("#select-choice-1").append('<option value='+res.rows.item(i).Category+'>'+res.rows.item(i).Category+'</option>');
                                                            }
                                               $("#select-choice-1").listview('refresh');
                                                          });
                                                   });
```

I have appended the loop and refreshed the list view. It works for me